# What are geodesic curves in static perfect fluid sphere?

Tags: general-relativity, geodesics

I have read that in perfect fluid only dust particles follow geodesics. If there is pressure in fluid, the particle trajectories are not geodesics [1]. My intention was to describe a static spacetime with perfect fluid sphere (Schwarzschild interior plus exterior solutions) by congruence of geodesics (integral curves). According to the referenced paper it would be possible only in vacuum region. Probably, I mix some notions here.

[1] https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.05891

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short:

---

The pressure $p$ arises from random motions of individual particles. The velocity $U^\mu$ does not capture
these individual random motions. It is rather an average velocity over all particles, or drift of the fluid.
In this average sense the fluid follows geodesics when pressure is constant.

If $p$ is not constant it is however no longer true that the fluid moves along geodesics. The pressure gradient leads to an additional force different
from gravitation.

---

***Zero Pressure***

To see how geodesics arise when $p=0$ recall that
the energy--momentum tensor of dust (or a pressure--less perfect fluid) is

\begin{eqnarray*}
T^{\mu\nu}=\rho\,U^\mu U^\nu\,.
\end{eqnarray*}
The law of conservation of energy-momentum in curved spacetime is

\begin{eqnarray}\tag{1}
0=\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=\rho\,U^\nu\nabla_\mu U^\mu + \rho\,U^\mu\nabla_\mu U^\nu + (\partial_\mu \rho)\,U^\mu U^\nu\,.
\end{eqnarray}
Multiplying this with $U_\nu$ and summation convention yields

\begin{eqnarray*}
0&=&\rho\,\underbrace{U^\nu U_\nu}_{=-1}\nabla_\mu U^\mu + \rho\,U^\mu\underbrace{U_\nu\nabla_\mu U^\nu}_{=0}+(\partial_\mu \rho)\,U^\mu \underbrace{U_\nu U^\nu}_{=-1}\\
&=&-\rho\,\nabla_\mu U^\mu -(\partial_\mu \rho)\,U^\mu=-\nabla_\mu (\rho\, U^\mu)\,,
\end{eqnarray*}
i.e., the four--divergence $\nabla_\mu (\rho\,U^\mu)$ is zero.
Combining the first and last term in the energy conservation law this can clearly be written as

\begin{eqnarray*}
0= U^\nu \nabla_\mu (\rho\, U^\mu) + \rho\,U^\mu\nabla_\mu U^\nu\,.
\end{eqnarray*}
Because we have just shown that the four-divergence in the first term is zero this collapses to

\begin{eqnarray*}
0=\rho\, U^\mu\nabla_\mu U^\nu \,.
\end{eqnarray*}
It is clear that in regions of non vanishing $U^\mu$ the density $\rho$ cannot be zero.
Therefore,

\begin{eqnarray}\tag{2}
0=U^\mu\nabla_\mu U^\nu \,.
\end{eqnarray}
This equation says that the four-momentum vector field is the tangent vector field of timelike geodesics.
In other words, the fluid particles move along geodesics.

***Non Zero Pressure***

When there is non zero pressure $p$ the energy--momentum tensor of the fluid is

\begin{eqnarray*}
T^{\mu\nu}=(\rho+p)\,U^\mu U^\nu+p\,g^{\mu\nu}\,.
\end{eqnarray*}
If $p$ is constant then $\nabla_\mu(p\,g^{\mu\nu})$ is zero (because $\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\nu}$ is metric compatible) and the energy conservation leads again to
(2).

Comment: Does it mean that there are no geodesics inside a perfect fluid sphere? I think one has to differentiate between geodesic particles movement (fluid particles) and geodesics as geometrical object.

Comment: @JanGogolin . Of course. When you have a metric tensor it has geodesics. And yes : you have to distinguish between them and the particles.

Comment: If you have neutrinos, dark matter or something that interacts only gravitationally their paths through the matter are also geodesics, only for stuff that interacts with the matter or the electric field are nongeodesic, which means you have some forces to add to your forcefree acceleration.

Comment: @Yukterez, would you mind to look at this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/700777/281096 ? I understand that in static spacetime of perfect fluid sphere I have all kind of geodesics. However, my circular geodesics would have zero angular momentum ($l=0$), like the radial ones. Is that correct?

Comment: That question in your link I don't understand. Circular geodesics should have angular momentum.

Comment: @Yukterez, if I understand it right, geodesic and test particle trajectory  are two different things. To have angular momentum one needs a particle with mass but geodesic is only a geometric object. If one takes some fluid element as test particle, with mass $\delta m=\rho \delta V$ than its angular velocity would be zero because of the static situation.

Answer (score 0):

Geodesics as integration curves of the geodesics equation depend only on metric. The questioner’s confusion has arisen from the vision of perfect fluid sphere as an impermeable solid, not allowing a free-fall movement for some test particle. However, this picture is not correct. Real matter is not continuous and can be penetrated without interaction. For example, a neutrino particle can traverse unhindered a matter clump following a time-like geodesic. The same is valid for a gravitation wave which however follows a null geodesic. By geodesics only metric is important.